# The username or password is incorrect in RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, rdp, authentication, mstsc

I trying to remote my desktop using `Remote Desktop Protocol(RDP)`.

I configure my desktop remote setting and put a check in remote assistance 
(Allow remote assistance connections to this computer) 
and also the second radio button in the remote desktop field 
(Allow connection fom computers running any version or RD).

But when I starting to remote my desktop using my laptop with `MSTSC` it brings me to the welcome screen (the blue screen) and I see it says the username or password is incorrect (at the bottom center above the word `"Window & Ultimate"`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just open your CMD, type net user and press enter.
2. You will see a list of user name here. This are the valid users of your computer.
3. Now please check the username you are using is available in the list.
4. if not then try any of the username from the list to connect through RDP. it should work.